# reinit breaks owl carousel

Tags: jquery, css

I had to add an reinit on my carousel, because the parent sections broke the layout on my owl carousel (v 1.3.3).

It looks like this:

```
var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
event.preventDefault();
$(".sectionID").removeClass("active");
target.addClass("active");
target.find(".service-line").data('owlCarousel').reinit();
target.find(".servicetext").data('owlCarousel').reinit();
```

Now it works fine in ff and opera, but on safari the owl carousel is broken from beginning on. After a window resize it all looks fine. But that is not the solution.

I found some people had problems with transitions and came up with following solution:

```
support3d = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length >= 1 && asSupport.length <= 2);
```

This is a replace. I just want to mention it, because it didn't work. So I suppose, the transition isn't affecting anything here.

If I delete the reinit, it works fine, but then I have the same problem again, which was solved by adding the reinit...

See this issue:
[Owl carousel breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202181/owl-carousel-breaks/39202477#39202477)

Is there a possibility to take out the reinit ONLY for safari? Which would be a dirty solution. If anyone knows a better one, I am open for anything....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code snippet to work adressing only safari:

```
var d = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
isSafari = (~d.indexOf("safari") && !~d.indexOf("chrome"));

if(isSafari) {
// do something for safari only
}else{
// don't
}
```

which solved my problem...